# Telerik MVC Extensions Grid Aggregate with Ajax Binding returns zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Well, i decided to give it a try to Telerik MVC Extensions v.2012.2.607.340

I am having a problem with aggregating a decimal field in their grid.

I am using ajax binding.

I have an Action that returns a json

```
return Json(data);
```

data is nothing but a List. it converts into json without problems. My grid is showing the data but the aggregation is not working. returns 0 (zero).
i am following their examples [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/aggregatesajax)

I went to their forum/community but i couldn't find any solution to this. maybe they dropped the ball since they made it into Kendo something and they are charging a "grand" for it.

Anyone has had the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something like this:

```
return Json(new { 
    Data = typeof(IEnumerable),
    Total = typeof(int),
    Aggregates = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)
});
```

You need to precalculate Aggregates though. Key of a Dictionary is name of the field, and its value is calculated aggregate.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct ? Because what if you request two aggregates on the same field, like sum(x) and average(x) ???

Comment: Yeah, because object is an array. Here is how I prepare it:
Dictionary<string, object> Aggs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Aggs[Field] = new { Sum = data.AsQueryable().Provider.Execute(Sum), Count = data.AsQueryable().Provider.Execute(Count) };

Comment: I not 100% sure this will work. I implemented it differently. See the KendoGridBinderEx project on GitHub and see this example page : http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/Employee/IndexGrouped3

Comment: Grid response is just a simple json object. It's up to you now to create it. That json object can have 'aggregates' (optional), 'data', 'total' and 'groups' (optional) properties. Case sensitive names, mind that. 'aggregates' property, in turn, can have properties which must be named like those of your model. And those properties then can have their properties named ['Sum', 'Count', 'Min', 'Max', 'Average']. As long as you return from server json object that comply to this you won't have a problem. How did you implement it? Why do you think this won't work?

Comment: Aggregates should be returned differently, see this example : http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/c56916

Comment: I am sorry, but how is this different? If you look at the right side of your example, it is easy to see that result conforms to everything i wrote before. Starting, of course, from array[4] (that is your response). On the left side is just JSON representation of result. That result will be created when you do: Json(new { Data = ..., Aggregates = ..., Total = ..., Groups = ... }). If you are using groups, then you also need to create JSONs for each group, but that's another issue.